# Data is recreated on page refresh

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, primefaces

I am developing an application using java and PrimeFaces. Below is the java code i have written:

```
class ShowRecordsManagedBean{
private List<RecordDTO> recordInfoList = null;
...
..
    public List<RecordDTO> getRecordList() {
        boolean flag=true;
        try {
            if(dataList==null){
                //logic here
                flag=false;
            }
            if(dataList!=null && flag){
                //Logic here
            } 
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        return dataList;
    }
```

Issue is when page loads each time the control has to go the below if condition:

```
   if(dataList==null){
        //logic here
        flag=false;
    }
```

But only for the time time, its going to the above mentioned if(..) condition, later even if i refresh the page its going to other if(..) present.

```
if(dataList!=null && flag){
            //Logic here
        }
```

How to modify the condition , that each time when i refresh the page it has to go to first if(..) condition, basically the object values are not becoming null even when page loads.I initialized all object to null initally while declaring. I need to close the browser or delete the cache to make control enter into other if(dataList!=null && flag) condition.

Modified as below:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ShowRecordsManagedBean {
    //fields declaration
private List<RecordsDTO> recordInfoList = null;
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        recordInfoList = null;
    }
    //getters, setters and other methods...
public List<RecordDTO> getRecordList(){
..
}
}
```

Still the problem not yet solved. When i refresh the page dataList should become null, but its holding previous value.
Please suggest.
Thanks.

Comment: Are you using JSF as well? Which version?

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza - Yes Primefaces4 and JSF2.

Comment: Is this also your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23682105/primefaces-conditional-check

Comment: @Mark Robinson - yes, i have deleted that thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your bean is created as `@RequestScoped`, so it will be recreated on every request. In order to make it live longer you should wide the scope at least to `@ViewScoped`. In this way, the bean will live while the client is in the same view, it is very useful when handling ajax requests in the same view.

Also, you should remove any business logic from the getters/setters of your fields since the getters may be called several times by the view (JSP or Facelets). You should load any initial data for your bean in a `@PostConstruct` annotated method.

Your bean should look like this:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ShowRecords {
    //fields declaration
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        //initialize your fields here
        //logifc to initialize dataList goes here
    }
    //getters, setters and other methods...
}
```

More info:

- [How to choose the right bean scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7031885/1065197)
- [Why JSF calls getters multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2090033/1065197)

---

Not part of the answer, but since you're using JSF 2 and PrimeFaces 4, you **should stop using JSP** as your view technology and move to [Facelets](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jsf-facelets.htm#GIEPX).

Comment: thanks for the help. But when iam modifying scope in ManagedBean to ViewScoped as you mentioned, its throwing the error " ViewScoped cannot be resolved to a type".

Comment: @user3633028 did you add the necessary imports? Are you using another library as well?

Comment: Thanks, i forgot to import the library. I will try and update you.

Comment: @user3633028 if this post solved your problem, don't forget to [mark it as the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/118694/182862).

Comment: still my probelm has not solved yet.The control is going to if(dataList!=null && flag) whenever i refresh the page. I added as you suggested.Please see the modified code in above post.

Comment: @user3633028 I don't see any modification in your post.

Comment: just posted, please check.

Comment: @user3633028 is your bean configured in faces-config.xml file as well? If so, remove that configuration.

Comment: @user3633028 you're welcome. If you start configuring your beans using annotations, remove the related bean configurations in faces-config.xml.

Comment: ok, thankyou. Iam using ajax request too so i believe ViewScoped would be better.